# What is Tomcat? A web container or EE container?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web

I am new to java web technology. It is said that java web applications have two containers:

- Web container
- EE container

What are these containers? And how do they collaborate?

Some say that Tomcat is a web container, whereas in some places it is said that Tomcat is an application server.What is Tomcat exactly?

If I say `web container + EE container = Application server` is it correct?

Comment: your question is partially answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181292/java-ee-containers-vs-web-containers

Answer (score 6):

Tomcat is just a Servlet container and also serves as a Web Server, that means it supports out-of-the-box Servlet API, JSF, Play framework, Spring (some set of features) and many others. On the other hand, Application Server is usually a superset of Servlet container which means that it contains all features that container has + all other Java EE capabilities like messaging, `EJB`, `JTA`, `JavaMail`, remoting and others.

So choice is mostly up to your requirements, however in the world of `CDI`, Servlet container should be sufficient for most applications (there is also transaction support from Java EE 7).

Some Servlet Containers

- Apache Tomcat
- Jetty

Some app servers

- JBoss AS (now Wildfly)
- Oracle WebLogic
- Glassfish

Answer (score 4):

Tomcat is a Servlet container. It's not a full fledged Java EE compliant Application Server, so it doesn't support for example `EJBs` or `JMS` out of the box.

Comment: tomcat is also considered as web server as given in the link in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I Think I myself found a reasonable answer for this via Wikepedia since nobody gave me a clear answer

> Java Platform, Enterprise Edition or Java EE (was J2EE) defines the
>   core set of API and features of Java Application Servers. The Web
>   modules include servlets, and JavaServer Pages. Enterprise JavaBeans
>   are used to manage transactions. According to the J2EE blueprints the
>   business logic of an application resides in Enterprise JavaBeans - a
>   modular server component providing many features, including
>   declarative transaction management, and improving application
>   scalability. Some Java Application Servers leave off many Java EE
>   features like EJB and JMS including Tomcat from Apache, and Jetty from
>   Eclipse Foundation. Their focus is more on Java Servlets and
>   JavaServer Pages.