# difference between Web Container and Web Browser

Tags: browser, web-container

What are the differences between two of them exactly?

also, I can't get their concepts.

I googled it, but couldn't find any web page which can tell the difference.

Anyone can help me understand these things?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java EE Containers vs Web Containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181292/java-ee-containers-vs-web-containers)

Comment: I mean, insofar as that explains what is meant by web container, it's not clear why you think that's something like a browser.

Comment: so what you're saying is those two terms aren't like similar or conflict concepts, right? like 'they're somehow related but on total different level' ?by the way, thanks for the link.